# Lookup last entry in each set in Excel

Tags: excel, vlookup

In Excel, if I have the following data in `Table1`:

```
Name  | Hobby
===============
James | Cooking
Phil  | Swimming
Phil  | Golfing
Eric  | Working
Eric  | Running
Eric  | Boarding
```

And the following `table2`:

```
Hobby    | Category
====================
Cooking  | Not Available
Swimming | Available
Golfing  | Available
Working  | Not Available
Running  | Available
Boarding | Available
```

> How do I return the `category` from `table2` of the ***last*** `hobby` per `name` in `table1`?

Ideally I get a result in an array/range that looks like:

```
 (Categories)
{"Not Available";   (Cooking from James)
 "Available";       (Golfing from Phil)
 "Available"}       (Boarding from Eric)
```

I know I can use `vlookup` or `index-match` to do a normal lookup to get the `category` of each `hobby`, but in this case, I am specifically interested in getting the ***last*** `hobby` per `name`, which I have not been able figure out or find after some searching.

Note, `Table1` may include blank `names` and/or `hobbies`. But the `names` themselves are grouped/sorted together.

Comment: Wouldn't it be immensely easier to include the names in the third table?

Comment: @Jeeped sure. Honestly I was thinking that the third table would be an array as unless it was a pivot table or something I don't know how the names would be dynamic. Also I do plan on then counting how many are `Available` and `Not Available` but I think that can still be done regardless of the `names` column being there or not.

Comment: Returning the last non-blank hobby per name and cross-referencing availability is easy enough given the name. If you want to add the difficulty of returning an ordinal list of unique names from a structured table reference, well then it may be just plain not worth it without vba.

Comment: Nevermind; your recent [edit] to now return a hard-coded array of values clears everything up.

Comment: @Jeeped How would you go about doing this? I can change it back if needed. Let's say I want to do the first option you brought up of cross-referencing availability. I would like to return an array of the results if that's possible.

Answer (score 0):

To make this simpler to read I have split formula across 2 columns in 3rd table. All 3 tables are Excel tables starting in the same row.

H2 and autofills down due to being Excel table

```
=VLOOKUP(INDEX(Table1[Hobby],MAX(IF(Table1[Name]=Sheet11!$G2,ROW(Table1[Name])-ROW(INDEX(Table1[Name],1,1))+1))),Table2[#All],2,FALSE)
```

And I2:

```
= [@Category] & ";  (" & INDEX(Table1[Hobby],MAX(IF(Table1[Name]=Sheet11!$G2,ROW(Table1[Name])-ROW(INDEX(Table1[Name],1,1))+1))) & " from " &[@Name] & ")"
```

---

Output:

[image: Data]

Comment: Did you try this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd approach the problem (no need for VBA):

here's the tables:

[image]

Now, in column C I used `VLOOKUP` in the following way:

```
=VLOOKUP(B2, $F$2:$G$7, 2, FALSE)
```

enter it in C2 cell and drag it down. Then, in D2 I entered a formula:

```
=IF(A2<>A3, C2 & " (" & B2 & " from " & A2 & ")", "")
```

and again, drag it all the way down.

Then you'll have the result as in the picture.

Comment: Good idea. But is there a way to make it return an array of just the results (or even if the results contain something like `false` between each result that is not the last). I am trying to avoid `A2<>A3` as I want to keep the results in one cell (as an array - yes I know arrays can span multiple cells) with the idea of then wrapping this in a `countif`